# Scala: exception handling in anonymous function

Tags: debugging, scala, exception, functional-programming

If I pass an anonymous function as an argument, like e.g. in this code sample:

```
val someMap = someData.map(line => (line.split("\\|")(0), // key 
                                    line.split("\\|")(1) + "|" + // value as string concat
                                    line.split("\\|")(4) + "|" +
                                    line.split("\\|")(9)))
```

I could catch, e.g. an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException like this:

```
try {
    val someMap = someData.map(line => (line.split("\\|")(0), // key 
                                        line.split("\\|")(1) + "|" + // value as string concat
                                        line.split("\\|")(4) + "|" +
                                        line.split("\\|")(9)))
} catch {
    case e1: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException => println("exception in line " )
}
```

The problem with this is that I do not have access to the inner function's scope. In this case I would like to print the `line` (from the anonymous function) which caused the exception.

How can I do this? Is there some way of catching an exception within an anonymous function? Is there a way to access the scope of an anonymous function from the outside for debugging purposes?

**edit:** I'm using Scala 2.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Either`

```
val result =
  someData.map {
    line =>
      try {
        val values = (line.split("\\|")(0), // key
          line.split("\\|")(1) + "|" + // value as string concat
            line.split("\\|")(4) + "|" +
            line.split("\\|")(9))
        Right(values)
      } catch {
        case e1: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException =>
          Left(s"exception in line $line")
      }
  }

result.foreach {
  case (Right(values)) => println(values)
  case (Left(msg)) => println(msg)
}
```

But if you are importing data from a text file, I would try to do it without exceptions (because it's not really exceptional to get invalid data in that case):

```
val result =
  someData.map {
    line =>
      val fields = line.split("\\|")
      if (fields.length < 9) {
        Left(s"Error in line $line")
      } else {
        val values = (fields(0), Seq(fields(1), fields(4), fields(9)))
        Right(values)
      }
  }

result.foreach {
  case (Right((key, values))) => println(s"$key -> ${values.mkString("|")}")
  case (Left(msg)) => println(msg)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this will give you some ideas:

```
try {
    val someMap = someData.map { line =>
            try {
                (line.split("\\|")(0), // key 
                 line.split("\\|")(1) + "|" + // value as string concat
                 line.split("\\|")(4) + "|" +
                 line.split("\\|")(9)))
            } catch {
                case inner: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException => {
                        println("exception in " + line)
                        throw inner;
                    }
            }
        }
} catch {
    case outer: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException => ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers give nice functional solutions using `Either` etc. If you were using Scala 2.10, you could also use `Try` as

```
val lines = List("abc", "ef");
println(lines.map(line => Try(line(3))));
```

to get `List[Try[Char]]`, where you can examine each element if it succeeded or failed. (I haven't tried to compile this.)

---

If for any reasons you prefer exceptions, you need to catch the exception inside the mapping function and rethrow it with information about the line. For example:

```
// Your own exception class holding a line that failed: 
case class LineException(line: String, nested: Exception)
  extends Exception(nested);

// Computes something on a line and throw a proper `LineException`
// if the processing fails:
def lineWorker[A](worker: String => A)(line: String): A =
  try {
    worker(line)
  } catch {
    case (e: Exception) => throw LineException(line, e);
  }

def getNth(lines: List[String], i: Int): List[Char]
  = lines.map(lineWorker(_.apply(i)));

val lines = List("abc", "ef");
println(getNth(lines, 1));
println(getNth(lines, 2));
```

You can also express it using `Catch` from `scala.util.control.Exception`:

```
case class LineException(line: String, nested: Throwable)
  extends Exception(nested); // we need Throwable here ^^

import scala.util.control.Exception._

// Returns a `Catch` that wraps any exception to a proper `LineException`.
def lineExceptionCatch[T](line: String): Catch[T]
  = handling[T](classOf[Exception]).by(e => throw LineException(line, e));

def lineWorker[A](worker: String => A)(line: String): A =
  lineExceptionCatch[A](line)(worker(line))

// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First your outer try/catch is useless. If you List (or other structure) is empty, `map` function won't do anything => no `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown.

As for the inner loop, i would sugest another solution with Scalaz Either:

```
import scalaz._
import EitherT._
import Id.Id

val someMap = someData.map { line =>
  fromTryCatch[Id, (String, String)] {
    (line.split("\\|")(0), // key
       line.split("\\|")(1) + "|" + // value as string concat
       line.split("\\|")(4) + "|" +
       line.split("\\|")(9))
  }
}
```

and then chain you operations on List[EitherT[...]]

Comment: He's cathing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` coming from indexing strings like in `line.split(...).(3)`, not from `map`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák that's the reason why he needs to wrap inner anonymous function, try/catch around map not requred